# Do a Task When Internet Connection is Available

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm Working in an Android project that generates data and then it registers that connecting to a WebService, the data can be created even if the user doesn't have an active internet connection in that moment. So, I want a way to run a function that calls the webservice and pass the data when a valid internet connection is detected, all in background. I have read about SyncAdapter and JobScheduler, but I'm very confused about these options because I'm very new in Android development, any help or suggestion  to decide which option is better to accomplish this would be very appreciated, thanks in after hand.

Answer (score 1):

You should use broadcast receiver. By that way you can check internet connection in a broadcast receiver and then do some stuff in background.

[this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) is a good tut to how use it.